# Invalid lookbehind pattern

Tags: regex, ruby

I am simply trying to take the following text:

```
Password length (length ordered)
5 = 1 (0.37%)   
6 = 1 (0.37%) 
7 = 1 (0.37%)         
8 = 157 (58.58%) 
9 = 55 (20.52%)
10 = 33 (12.31%)
11 = 12 (4.48%)                  
12 = 6 (2.24%)                   
13 = 2 (0.75%)
```

And find every new line that exists between `Password Length` and `\n\n`. Here's what I was currently doing

```
data[/(?<=Password length)(.*?)(?=\n\n)/m]
```

but that captures  `(length ordered)` in the first line.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
44] pry(main)> data[/(?<=Password length.*?\n)(.*?)(?=\n\n)/m]
(eval):2: invalid pattern in look-behind: /(?<=Password length.*?\n)(.*?)(?=\n\n)/m
```

To basically capture everything after `Password length` up to the new line, but as you can see above I get an error about the invalid pattern in look-behind.

What should I be doing instead of this to fix this?

Comment: Try `/(?:\G(?!\A)|Password length).*\K\R(?!\R)/`

Comment: The end result is just `\n` rather than everything starting from the 2nd line throughout the last line with 13 on it

Comment: You asked to get all *new*lines. Ok, you need `data[/Password length.*\R(?m:(.*?))\R{2}/, 1]` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
data[/Password length.*\R(?m:(.*?))\R{2}/, 1]
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/BJTSxW39G431zY). **Details**:

- `Password length` - a literal string
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `(?m:(.*?))` - An inline modifier group where `.` matches any char including line break chars, capturing group 1 matching any zero or more chars but as few as possible
- `\R{2}` - double line break sequence.

The `1` argument returns the value inside the first capturing group only  (see [the `str[regexp, capture] → new_str or nil` reference](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)).

An alternative:

```rb
data[/Password length.*\R\K.*(?:\R(?!\R).*)*/]
```

See [this Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/7vxMb08H5Ob7nf). Details:

- `Password length.*\R` - `Password length`, the rest of the line and a line break sequence
- `\K` - match reset operator, it removes all text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `.*` - a line, any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:\R(?!\R).*)*` - zero or more lines that do not end with double line break sequence where `\R(?!\R).*` matches a line break not immediately followed with another line break sequence, and `.*` matches the rest of the line.

Comment: This did the trick for me and also taught me something new. I really appreciate!!

Comment: @LewlSauce I added an alternative solution that matches what you need into Group 0, the whole match.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is perfect. I really appreciate the breakdown and explanation between the two as well.